# *.deps.json and *.runtimeconfig.json files are not copied from NuGet package

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have a .NET 6 project `MyProject` which is referencing a NuGet package. The NuGet package contains a `MyHost.exe` and `MyHost.runtimeconfig.json` and `MyHost.deps.json` files, all in `lib\net6.0` folder.

The problem is that when I publish `MyProject` the `MyHost.runtimeconfig.json` and `MyHost.deps.json` files are not copied to the output folder.

I've tried `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` and `<IncludeAssets>all</IncludeAssets>` in PackageReference but it didn't help. There is also a proposed solution with adding *.targets file to NuGet package which looks like a heavy artillery.

Since `runtimeconfig.json` file is required I would think there should be a straightforward way to have it automatically copied.

Comment: NuGet is designed to be a library manager, not an app distribution tool. Well, `dotnet tool`s are actually distributed by NuGet, but it has different packaging conventions, and setting a property in the project will cause the package to be created in the correct way. Anyway, since `runtimeconfig.json` is not used in scenarios that NuGet is typically used, I wouldn't assume that there's a straightforward way to have it included.

Comment: given the edit, if you're the author of the package, you can put the runtimeconfig.json file under `contentFiles/any/any/`, and then it should be copied to the consuming project's output directory on build & publish.

Comment: Thanks, @zivkan. But although NuGet is a library manager I think it's a valid case to have some kind of hosting application to be packaged into NuGet package. As for `contentFiles` the problem is that runtimeconfig.json is a generated file so I don't see an easy way to include it and build a package with `dotnet pack`.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach worked.
I've created a `<NuGet package name>.props` file in `build` folder of the project with the following content:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="AddRuntimeDependenciesToContent"
          Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp'"
          BeforeTargets="GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems"
          DependsOnTargets="GenerateBuildDependencyFile;
                            GenerateBuildRuntimeConfigurationFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ContentWithTargetPath Include="$(ProjectDepsFilePath)" TargetPath="MyHost.deps.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
      <ContentWithTargetPath Include="$(ProjectRuntimeConfigFilePath)" TargetPath="MyHost.runtimeconfig.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

and added this folder to `MyHost.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="build\**" Pack="True" PackagePath="build\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This way any project referencing this NuGet package gets the `*.props` file automatically "appended" to the `*.csproj` file. As the result `*.runtimeconfig.json` and `*.deps.json` files are copied to the build output.